# Galleria not clearing caption

Tags: jquery, galleria

I am using Galleria and extending it to show the caption's created from image alt attributes. It works great, however if I choose to have no caption on one image, the caption from the image before is still visible, I notice also that the Galleria info container, where I get my captions from; doesn't update if the alt attribute is empty.

Is there any way to rectify this?

Here is my code.

```
jQuery("body").find('.galleria').galleria({
                    autoplay: false,
                    image_crop: false, // crop all images to fit
                    thumb_crop: false, // crop all thumbnails to fit
                    image_position: 'top left',
                    transition: 'fade', // crossfade photos
                    transition_speed: 700, // slow down the crossfade
                    show_counter: false, // crossfade photos
                    extend: function() {

                        this.bind(Galleria.IMAGE, function(e) {

                            var caption = this.$('info-description').html();
                            //alert(caption)
                            if(this.$('info-description').html() == ""){
                                jQuery("body").find('.caption').html();
                            }else{
                                jQuery("body").find('.caption').html(this.$('info-description').html());
                            }

                        })
                    }

             });//end galleria
```

I know this is specialised but someone is bound to have come across this problem before. Any suggestions would be amazing.

All the best
Tara

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an empty string when you set the caption:

```
jQuery("body").find('.caption').html('');
```

If no string is specified in [`html(..)`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) then it returns the value instead of setting it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm not sure where I would add this code. Unfortunately an XML file populates the galleria so I can't access which image has no caption except via galleria itself. Could I add it to the extend function?

Comment: Add it under `if(this.$('info-description').html() == ""){`

Comment: :( it didn't work. the caption is not clearing in the info description div which is galleria itself. I guess I need a if empty add &nbsp; or something..